# jquery add padding on div by finding outer parent div height

Tags: jquery, html

i need to add top-padding half of  parent total DIV height in child DIV. there is fixed height of parent DIV.

example : http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ab4ev6mc4

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inside"> need here top-padding</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the height of Parent is fixed then why not do it by CSS instead of jQuery, Simply adding `padding-top : half-of-parent-height;` will do the trick

Comment: thank you but there is no fixed of main div

Comment: Why do you write "there is fixed height of parent div" then? This should be solved in CSS, not by DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inside").css({"padding-top":$(".main").height()/2+"px"});
});
```

This will add the `padding` to `.inside`. **Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tp2qbj7L/)**

Comment: Sorry their was typo, Code updated with added fiddle.

Comment: If you set the html,body height to 100% then you can use the same code:
http://jsfiddle.net/tp2qbj7L/1/

Comment: Yes you can use that, Jquery `.height()` automatically calculates the height in `px`. You can apply `margin` the same way which will remove the so much dark grey from `.inner`. Is this what you wanted? Please upvote and mark it as correct answer, if it solves your problem.

Comment: Their is a check mark near the top of my answer where a big 0 is written